# saving user input data in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to store last file paths that user opened via the application.
And on next opening of the application to present it back to him.

What is the recommended way doing so in WPF application ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Settings file to your application through the Project Properties and Settings Tab.
Name this settings `LastUserSelectedPath`,  select a String Type, and most important, choose a User setting. Leave the Value empty.

Now, in your application, you could read this property using

```
 string uPath = Properties.Settings.Default.LastUserSelectedPath;
```

and you can write it back with

```
string newSelectedPath = SomeMethodThatReturnsTheNewPath();
Properties.Settings.Default.LastUserSelectedPath = newSelectedPath;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Note that this works *per user basis*. A different user, also if it runs on the same machine, will have a different setting.
Don't forget to add the

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the OpenFileDialog control, you can set the [RestoreDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) property to `true` before calling ShowDialog. I believe this stores the last directory for you in the registry but only if the user clicks `OK` rather than `Cancel`.